# Binding something to a moving object

Tags: effects

Many montages on youtube use some kind of binding things(text, images) to some moving objects. For example this guy uses binding on game character:

I made something similar in Sony Vegas but that looks like garbage even after all the keyframes I made to move the text synchronously to object. Is there any better way to make something similar and which program will do the best job here? What is the name of this effect and how to find(search for) it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is Motion Tracking. There are a number of tools which have motion trackers in them - [Apple's Motion](http://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/motion/), [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html), and more. There are also 3rd party trackers like [Mocha](http://www.imagineersystems.com), [Core Melt Track X](http://www.coremelt.com/products/trackx-powered-by-mocha.html), etc.

The workflow will differ depending on which tool you're using, so I can't really get into details here. But you should be able to find tutorials on YouTube and at the vendors' websites.